# InvalidArgumentError: indices[120,0] = 3080 is not in [0, 32) [[{{node embedding_6/embedding_lookup}}]]

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm

I have seen others have posted similar questions. But the difference is I'm running a Keras Functional API instead of a sequential model.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras import layers
from keras import Input
text_vocabulary_size = 10000
question_vocabulary_size = 10000
answer_vocabulary_size = 500

text_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='text')
embedded_text = layers.Embedding(64, text_vocabulary_size)(text_input)
encoded_text = layers.LSTM(32)(embedded_text)
question_input = Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32', name='question')
embedded_question = layers.Embedding( 32, question_vocabulary_size)(question_input)
encoded_question = layers.LSTM(16)(embedded_question)

concatenated = layers.concatenate([encoded_text, encoded_question],axis=-1) 

## Concatenates the encoded question and encoded text

answer = layers.Dense(answer_vocabulary_size, activation='softmax')(concatenated)
model = Model([text_input, question_input], answer)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

### Feeding data to a multi-input model

```
import numpy as np
num_samples = 1000
max_length = 100

text = np.random.randint(1, text_vocabulary_size, size=(num_samples, max_length))

question = np.random.randint(1, question_vocabulary_size,  size=(num_samples, max_length))

answers = np.random.randint(0, 1, size=(num_samples, answer_vocabulary_size))
```

### Fitting using a list of inputs

```
model.fit([text, question], answers, epochs=10, batch_size=128)
```

The error I get while trying into fitting the model is as follows.

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[120,0] = 3080 is not in [0, 32)
     [[{{node embedding_6/embedding_lookup}}]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension of the vocabulary is the first parameter to the `Embedding` class, you are setting them as the second. You just have to switch the parameters you are giving to the embedding instances.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect using layers.Embedding(text_vocabulary_size, 64)(text_input)